# Is it possible to accelerate my data drive using the same SSD Windows is installed on using Intel SRT?

Tags: ssd, cache, smart-response

I have a 240GB SSD with Windows 7 installed. **It also has an unallocated 64GB partition, which I reserved to use Intel Smart Response Technology.**

I would like to accelerate a mechanical drive that is solely reserved for data.

SATA is set to RAID (and was so before I installed Windows) and both disks are connected to the Intel controller. However in the Intel Rapid Storage Technology utility, I only get the option to create a RAID.

From prior reading, what I want to do [appears to be possible](http://www.overclock.net/t/1404323/guide-using-1-ssd-as-system-drive-os-and-acceleration-drive-raid-smart-response-technology-ssd-caching).

Please can someone with experience of using their SSD as both a boot drive and cache tell me what I am doing wrong?

*For clarity - I am not trying to accelerate a mechanical drive that has the OS installed on it.*

Comment: [This](http://superuser.com/questions/319778/acceleration-not-available-in-intel-srt-menu?rq=1) question has been asked before

Comment: @Ramhound that question is unrelated. The (large) difference is, I have installed Windows on the SSD which I would like to use as a cache. The drive I wish to accelerate is solely data.

Comment: So you checked and verified the drive is using the Intel RAID driver?

Comment: @Ramhound yes, hence the ability to create a RAID array in the utility.

Comment: [You can't have any partitions on the drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/609392/intel-rapid-storage-refuses-to-work-no-button-in-srt-utility?rq=1) and [this](http://superuser.com/questions/546601/no-accelerate-button-tab-on-intel-rapid-storage-window?rq=1) explain the reasons.

Comment: You can't have any partitions on the drive if you want to use accelerate feature even if its just the data drive.

Comment: @Ramhound I appreciate your persistence, but that simply isn't true. Caching is limited to 64GB and it is possible to utilise the remaining space with another partition. Copying from another answer in attempt to answer mine, really isn't helping me. But if you do somehow find an answer, please type it as one and I will mark it correct.

Comment: But from what I can determine in order to setup the accelerate feature it wants zero partitions.

Comment: @Ramhound I think you are right. Intel says "Deploying both Intel® Smart Response Technology and [x] requires creating partitions and installing...in a specific sequence." Section 1.4.6 on pg. 20-21 in the [SRT Deployment Guide](http://downloadmirror.intel.com/22501/eng/Intel%20SRT%20Enterprise%20Deployment%20Guide%20Rev%202.0.pdf) is particularly interesting.